# Momentum of a relativistic atom

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum, atoms, doppler-effect

I have been solving a problem where you should derive the formula for doppler effect when a source of light is an atom moving at a relativistic velocity v. I understood everything in the solution except for why was the formula for impulse of the atom used as if it's not relativistic i.e. p=m*v?
Is it maybe because the atom is so heavy that the lorentz factor wouldn't change the momentum noticeably?

Comment: Someone made some error somewhere :)   Maybe recoil effect was calculated in the atom frame, that's what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong on writing the relativistic momentum as $p = mv$ as long as you are saying that $m = \gamma m_0$, where $m_0$ is the rest mass (inertial mass). In other words, the equation $p = mv$ is relativistic, the Lorentz factor is simply compacted onto the mass, meaning that the mass you are using to calculate isn't the rest mass but rather the relativistic mass.

Comment: You might want to point out that most physicists no longer use the concept of relativistic mass as pointed out by many other answers for example: [relativistic mass and graivty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339054/relativistic-mass-and-gravity).

Comment: @M.Enns I know. But that's not the case for most undergrad books (I'm here assuming that the asker is an undergrad)

Comment: Thank you, everyone, it turns out that the author actually used relativistic mass which we didn't use before for the reasons you already mentioned and I didn't even think of using it.